# Load unistall icon from exe file in the inno setup

Tags: icons, inno-setup, uninstallation

I have all of my icons in my executable file. If I want to change the uninstall icon of my program which is shown in Start Menu, I can easily do that by:

```
[Files]
Source: "icons\uninstall.ico"; DestDir: "{app}\Icons"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: "{app}\Icons\Uninstall.ico"
```

Since I have Unistall.ico in my exe file, I want load the icon from it, but the below line doesn't do that and causes no icon is displayed in the **Start Menu > My Program Folder**

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},5"
```

Whats wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

",5" is not a valid part of the filename.  Replace it with this:

```
IconFilename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; IconIndex: 5
```

(Assuming of course that you do have at least 6 icon resources in your application.)